# How to set the font size for code blocks in pandoc markdown?

Tags: latex, pandoc

this small example:

```
An example code snippet:

~~~{.cpp}
class A 
{
    public:
        static void f1 () {}; 

        virtual void f2 () = override; 
};
~~~
```

can be used to generate a PDF output with:

```
pandoc -o block-code.pdf block-code.txt
```

resulting in

[image: Font sizes of the code snippet and the text are equal.]

The font sizes of both the code and the text that are equal. How can I change the font size of the code snippets for the pdf (LaTex) pandoc output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this problem for me by writing several LaTeX snippets into extra files I keep around:

```
 cat make-code-footnotesize.tex

   \renewenvironment{Shaded} {\begin{snugshade}\footnotesize} {\end{snugshade}}
```

I have such snippets for all different sizes: `huge`, `LARGE`,  `Large`, `large`, `normalsize`, `small`, `footnotesize`, `scriptsize`, `tiny`.

To apply them when running `pandoc`, just include the respective LaTeX snippet with the `-H` parameter:

```
 pandoc -o block-code.pdf block-code.txt \
    -H make-code-scriptsize.tex --highlight-style=espresso
```

**Result:**

[image]

***Note***, this controls the font sizes for *all* code blocks in the PDF. It does not allow you to vary sizes from block to block. Of course, it also doesn't work for HTML, ODT, EPUB or other output -- only for LaTeX and PDF output.

Comment: Can the `renewenvironment` be added to a pandoc Latex template? I've tried adding it and after adding `\usepackage{framed}` I get an error message `! LaTeX Error: Undefined color `shadecolor'`.

Comment: @tmaric: The Shaded environment will only become active if you use syntax highlighting.

Comment: I get the same `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color 'shadecolor'.` whenever I try a style not espresso. I was able to define it by adding `\colorlet{shadecolor}{white}` to my template.

Comment: This is the way to go. But it only works with highlighting styles that have a special background. see here: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.9.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Highlighting.html#v:formatLaTeXBlock

Else you have to leave out the begin and end of the snugshade environment:

\renewenvironment{Shaded} {\footnotesize} {}

Answer (score 18):

You can simply add `\small` before the beginning of the code snippet and `\normalsize` after (to return to normal).

You can also add other similar commands. For instance, if your document is doublespaced, you can add `\singlespace` before the code snippet and `\doublespacing` after.

For this to work you need to add in the yaml at the beginning of your document the following:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
---
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! And I didn't even need to include the package in the header.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Because I've been unable to locate something more comprehensive about what can be used in slides for beamer output from markdown.

Comment: @Álex I think you can use any latex with beamer output. Pretty much any time you find that markdown can't do something, you can just switch to latex in mid-stream.

Answer (score 7):

I've developed a filter for pandoc https://github.com/chdemko/pandoc-latex-fontsize for this purpose:

Install this filter with `pip`:

```
$ pip install pandoc-latex-fontsize
```

add for example

```
---
pandoc-latex-fontsize:
  - classes: [c, listing]
    size: footnotesize
---
```

to your metadata block and specify the listings you want to be of size `footnotesize`:

```
~~~{.c .listing}
int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
~~~
```

then run pandoc with

```
$ pandoc --filter pandoc-latex-fontsize ...
```

Answer (score 3):

On pandoc 1.16.0.2 I did get the same problem but wasn't solved by previous answers.

When using default code highlighting of this version and exporting it with beamer (`-t beamer`) I got following generated output (for outputting a jmeter command):

```
\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{./jmeter.sh} \NormalTok{-q prod.properties -p jmeter.properties  -n -t mytest.jmx -l mylog.log}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}
```

By searching directly in the pandoc code with `grep -r "Highlighting" *` I found following code:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\}}
```

And I replaced it with the following to have a tiny font size in my custom pandoc template (see `pandoc -D beamer`):

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{commandchars=\\\{\},fontsize=\tiny}
```

Now I have a tinier font size by running the following command:

```
pandoc -t beamer input.md -o output.pdf --template beamer.template
```

Answer (score 2):

I use pandoc with the `--listings` option and a custom `eisvogel.latex` template.

- Download the original [eisvogel-template](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/master/eisvogel.tex) to a new file `eisvogel_custom.latex`
- Open the file, find the line `basicstyle = \color{listing-text-color}\small\ttfamily{}\linespread{1.15},`
- Change the `\small` to `\footnotesize`, or `\tiny`
- Save the file

Now run pandoc with the following options:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex --template=eisvogel_custom --listings -o block-code.pdf block-code.txt
```

To disable the line-numbering, add the following lines at the top of `block-code.txt`

```
---
listings-disable-line-numbers: true
...
```

All options can be found here: https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template#custom-template-variables

Tested with pandoc 2.6 using docker-image [dalibo/pandocker:stable](https://hub.docker.com/r/dalibo/pandocker/)